# How did scientist calculate Higgs boson mass without measurement?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, standard-model, higgs, approximations

First of all, let us write out the lagrangian of the Higgs field

$\mathcal{L}=\partial_\mu\bar{\varphi}\partial^\mu\varphi-\lambda(\bar{\varphi}\varphi-\frac{v^2}{2})^2$

This yields $m^2=\lambda v^2$. The constant $v$ can be easily found from masses of W- and Z-bosons, since $m_W=\frac{gv}{2}$ and $m_Z=\frac{gv}{2\,cos\,\theta_W}$

The problem is to find $\lambda$, because it appears only in self-interaction of Higgs field.

So, my question is how did scientist approximated Higgs field without experimental measurement before actually measurement by the LHC?

Comment: I don’t think there was an estimate, just bounds from above and below. Is the question where these bounds came from?

Comment: Yes, I am interested how bounds were calculated

Comment: when I google "estimate of higgs mass" a number of articles appear . examples  https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.3753  ,  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269301014496

Answer (score 2):

The Higgs boson's vacuum expectation value and mass are non-computable in the SM, that is they are free parameters.

Particle Physicists expected the mass of the Higgs Boson to be at around the Planck scale, as per the expectations that quantum corrections would drive the energy scale up to the point where quantum gravity is no longer negligible, and in fact that particle's failing to do so has a name, as a problem, the **hierarchy problem**.

What one can do however is to look at particles that do couple to a field, and by looking at the other known physics, come up with bounds based on the energy scales. For example, if you have a particle x, and you suspect that it decays into a particle y or z+w, then all, respectively decay into particles k, l+m, n+o, then by knowing from other experiments how the z and w particles decay, you can find bounds for y from your results from x decays.

In 2009 they estimated the mass to be around 126 GeV by considering asymptotic safety of gravity. For the details please see the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0208)

Comment: Planck scale is about at $10^{19}~GeV/c^2$ while [Higgs boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson) mass is on the order $10^2~GeV/c^2$,- that's off by 17 orders of magnitude ! Hence, I don't believe that somebody could "mis-predict" Higgs boson to be at Planck scale. In addition, Higgs boson lays on [metastable area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Higgs-Mass-MetaStability.svg), while Planck scale is _extremely unstable_. So these two branches (Higgs field vs Planck scale) are not compatible at all.

Comment: @MrDBrane, I think you misunderstood his question. It's not about "why" the Higgs mass (and therefore the mass of the Z and W bosons) **should** be much lower than the Planck scale. Rather, the question is, since we already know that the Z and W bosons are relatively (to Planck scale) light, the Higgs mass should also be on a similar light scale - but before it was found in the LHC, how accurately did we guess the HIggs mass given the known Z and W masses - and how did we make these guesses?
E.g., we found the HIggs at 125.35 GeV. Could it have been at 1253.5 GeV? Or we knew it couldn't?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas As I said, the idea is that radiative corrections drive it up there. That means that there should exist some mechanism that protects the Higgs mass. See MSSM for an example of that. The absence of evidence for such mechanism is called the hierarchy problem.

Comment: @NadavHar'El I added a relevant paper, thank you for the comment.